# Capturar longitud de una cadena sin espacios en blanco sin incluir en la longitud etiquetas

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Llevo todo el día intentando hallar la solución a este problema. Tengo un texto (html) que leer y modificar. Dentro del mismo hay dos tipos de etiquetas con las que no quiero hacer match, etiquetas html (es decir, entre `<` y `>`) y etiquetas que abren con `[` y cierran con `]`. Dentro de estas etiquetas, podemos encontrar direcciones URL, comillas dobles `"` y otros caracteres típicos del etiquetado HTML.

El documento completo sobre el que voy a trabajar tiene, además de las etiquetas mencionadas, texto normal que me deforma el ancho de mi página web porque, algunas partes, en lugar de contener espacios en blanco, contienen `&nbsp;`. Sin embargo, no puedo hacer un `/&nbsp;/g` y reemplazo por `\s` de esos espacios en blanco porque alteran la disposición de las imágenes de la página (y son 400 páginas así, por lo que quiero evitar tener que modificar a mano esa posición).

Mi idea había sido pues la de capturar el texto que rebasara más de cierto número de caracteres sin espacios naturales en blanco `\s` y si hay `&nbsp;` en su interior, en este caso sí, reemplazarlo (aunque es cierto que existe el riesgo de que me deforme la posición de las imágenes pero es mucho menor). Los problemas que tengo son los siguientes:

1. He de evitar seleccionar texto que esté dentro de las etiquetas mencionadas, `< > y [ ]`.
2. Pese a no seleccionar ese texto, hay que tenerlo en cuenta, ya que si mi límite de caracteres fuese de 30 y no tuviera en cuenta las etiquetas html, no haría match en este caso:

   `abcdfghijklmnño<i>pqrstuvxyzqwerty`

   Este texto tiene una longitud de 30 caracteres seguidos, sin espacios en blanco, pero si se captura la etiqueta aparte, sólo veremos dos textos de 15 caracteres cada uno. No se me ocurre la manera de capturar de una forma continuada, así como tampoco sé cómo evitar que haga la captura de las etiquetas y su interior si quiero evitar que busque una longitud de caracteres mayor que, por ejemplo, 30.

Algunos ejemplos, además del anterior, serían los siguientes:

`/&nbsp;<a href="http://elpais.com/diario/1978/02/22/sociedad/256950016_850215.html" style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial; display: inline; ">"Tienda&nbsp;<i>País</i>&nbsp;21.1.56`

En este caso debería hacer match porque sobrepasa la longitud de caracteres (37 sin contar etiquetas ni su contenido interior), si bien cada espacio en blanco `&nbsp;` ocupa seis en lugar de uno.

```
padre&nbsp;<b>Terreros:</b></span></div>
```

En este caso, el texto completo tiene una longitud de 40 caracteres pero, si no contamos las etiquetas, su longitud es tan solo de 20, así que no debería seleccionar este texto.

Sé que está terriblemente mal, porque hace muchas selecciones innecesarias (no sé cómo evitarlas) y no selecciona bien lo que yo quiero (no tiene en cuenta que haya etiquetas por medio), pero esta es la regex que he llegado a hacer.

`/(?:(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+\]|["]))+|([a-z0-9áéíóúüñ\_\/\=\%\$\&\)\;\.\:\(\?\-\<\>]{35,})/gi`

Contemplo la opción de que, en este caso, no sea posible conseguir mediante expresiones regulares lo que necesito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Antes de responder**

Para procesar HTML, en realidad se debería usar un [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Justamente en JavaScript, las propias funciones del lenguaje te permiten hacerlo correctamente. La forma de hacerlo, sería recorriendo cada uno de los nodos de texto de tu HTML, y revisando ahí si se continúan uno con otro por más de 30 caracteres.

Además, no es lo mismo que sea una etiqueta `<i>` como en tu ejemplo, que un `<div>` o `<p>`, que van a cortar el texto, por más que esté continuado. Sin embargo, eso haría una respuesta un tanto más larga, por lo que continúo respondiendo específicamente a tu pregunta de regex, si y sólo si están claros los riesgos.

¿Cuáles son los riesgos? Aparte de no estar identificando la semántica de cada etiqueta, regex no es la herramienta para analizar HTML. Por ejemplo, estás usando algo bastante simplista en tu regex: `/<[^>]+>/`, pero siempre vas a encontrar alguna excepción en la sintaxis de HTML. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" value="esto > te rompe el patrón">
<!-- o esto > también -->
```

Y esos casos se pueden incorporar en la lógica del regex, pero después aparece otro como
[`<![CDATA[`…`]]>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect), y luego otra excepción, y otra, y otra...

Ni siquiera un regex de 1000 caracteres te va a servir para analizar HTML correctamente. Por eso, para HTML, regex no es la solución, para eso están las funciones de JavaScript que lo tratan como un DOM. Y creo que se puede ver un patallazo de la complejidad cuando llegues al final de esta respuesta.

Podríamos asumir que todo tu HTML es simple, y que no se va a romper si usamos `<[^>]+>`, pero tiene que estar muy claro que es una solución muy simplista, en la que estamos asumiendo demasiado.

---

Si nos permitimos asumir que el HTML es básico, entonces sí vamos a ver cómo responder, pero estarías asumiendo este riesgo.

### Solución para tags simples, que no tienen un `>` adentro

**Estructura base**. La idea es coincidir con 30 caracteres consecutivos que no sean espacios en blanco excepto un NBSP, para reemplazarlos siguiendo una cierta lógica:

```
html.replace( /(^|[^\S\xa0])([\S\xa0]{30,})/g, function (m, carPrevio, textoLargo) {
    textoLargo = tuLogicaParaCorregir( textoLargo );
    return carPrevio + textoLargo;
});
```

que coincide con:

- `(^|[^\S\xa0])` - Grupo 1 (caracter previo) - El inicio del texto, o un caracter que sea un espacio en blanco (excepto `\xa0` que es un NBSP).

  ¿Por qué esa clase de caracteres? Porque un NBSP está incluido dentro de `\s` en la mayoría de las implementaciones modernas de JavaScript (depende de navegador o versión), pero tenemos que excluirlo de `\s`.

  La lógica de `[^\S\xa0]` es un *doble negativo*: un caracter:

  - que **no** sea un "**no** espacio en blanco" (`\S`) -o sea, un espacio en blanco.
  - que **no** sea un NBSP (`\xa0`).
- `([\S\xa0]{30,})` - Grupo 2 (texto largo) - 30 o más consecutivos que no sean un espacio en blanco, o que sean un NBSP.

Y luego, dentro del `replace()` usamos una función para aplicar la lógica que quieras para modificar ese texto largo: sea reemplazar los NBSP por espacios, o lo que prefieras hacer.

<sub>* Quizás te preguntes por qué estoy haciendo coincidir al caracter previo, si no hay ningún motivo para compararlo. Simplemente es por un tema de eficiencia. Al forzar a que la coincidencia esté anclada al espacio previo a la palabra, se reducen la cantidad de lugares iniciales desde donde puede intentar coincidencias fallidas. De hecho, con el texto del código de más abajo, se reduce de 15224 pasos a 6068 pasos al usar ese caracter.</sub>

**Ignorar las etiquetas**. Ahora bien, dentro de ese `[\S\xa0]{30,}` tenemos que ver la forma de que no cuente los tags. Para empezar, excluimos a los caracteres `<` y `[`:

```
(?:[^\s<[]|\xa0){30,}
```

Y luego, permitimos que coincida con cualquier cantidad de tags antes de cada caracter:

```
(?:(?:<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])*(?:[^\s<[]|\xa0)){30,}
```

De esta forma, estamos haciendo un bucle, en el que puede haber cualquier cantidad de tags, pero siempre 1 único caracter por fuera del tag, y ese bucle está repetido 30 o más veces:

[image: Bucle expresado en estados del NFA según visualización de debuggex,com]

**Contar entidades HTML como 1 caracter**. En tu pregunta, estás contando a los `&nbsp;` como si fueran 6 caracteres, pero en realidad, en el HTML se renderizan como 1 único caracter. Para contarlo como 1, deberíamos usar una lógica similar a lo que usamos con los tags. Excluimos a `&` de la clase de caracteres, e incluyendo `&\w+;` para que lo cuente una vez por iteración. Pero también tenemos que incluir a `&(?!\w+;)` para que cuente a los `&` que no son parte de entidades HTML:

```
(?:(?:<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])*(?:[^\s<[&]|\xa0|&(?:\w+;|(?!\w+;)))){30,}
```

[image: debuggex.com]

**Aún falta un caso**. Parecía que con el regex anterior ya teníamos todo. Sin embargo, falta tener en cuenta cuando no encuentra una palabra larga, puede llegar a coincidir dentro de un tag

```
<tag porque_el_motor_de_RegExp_puede_iniciar_la_coincidencia_aca="aahhh!">
//   |
//   |
//   +---> nada impide que intente desde acá si no coincidió con otra palabra larga
```

Lo ideal es utilizar el modificador [`y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) ([sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky)). Sin embargo, IE [no lo soporta](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags) (maldito IE arruinándonos todo de nuevo).

Para evitar ese comportamiento, vamos a usar un truco. RexEgg.com lo llama *[el mejor truco de regex de la historia](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)*. Consiste en coincidir con lo que no queremos que coincida, para usarlo en el reemplazo sin modificar nada. Es decir:

```
/(lo que no queremos)|nuestro regex/
```

y usando `$1` sin modificar en el reemplazo.

Para ignorar las etiquetas, sería:

```
/(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])|nuestro regex/g
```

**Uniendo las partes**. Finalmente, nos queda el regex:

```
/(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])|(^|[^\S\xa0])((?:(?:<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])*(?:[^\s<[&]|\xa0|&(?:\w+;|(?!\w+;)))){30,})/g
```

que va a coincidir con un tag, o un texto de 30 o más caracteres, sin contar los tags.

[image: debuggex.com]

Bien, ya tenemos la coincidencia de los 30+ caracteres, con cualquier cantidad de tags en el medio, pero...

**¿Y cómo reemplazar los `&nbsp;` o NBSP literales por un espacio?** Dentro de la función que pasamos al `replace()`, también tenemos que asegurarnos de que al reemplazar los caracteres, éstos no estén dentro de un tag. Es decir, vamos a tener un replace *adentro* de otro replace:

```
html = html.replace( regex1, function (m, carPrevio, textoLargo) {

    // Acá tenemos seleccionado el texto de 30+ con tags
    textoLargo = textoLargo.replace( regex2, function (m, grupo1) {

        //Acá vamos a reemplazar los NBSP que no estén en un tag
        return /* ... */;

    });

    return /* ... */;
});
```

Y para reemplazar los que no están en un tag volvemos a aplicar el truco de recién, es decir:

```
/(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])|&nbsp;|\xa0/ig
```

#### Código:

```js
// texto HTML
let html = [
      'laaaaaaaaaar&nbsp;gooooooooooooooo&nbsp;oooooooo',
      '',
      'no haría match en este caso',
      '(en realidad coincide, pero lo devuelve sin modificar):',
      'abcdfghijklmnño<i>pqrstuvxyzqwerty',
      '',
      'Algunos ejemplos, además del anterior, serían los siguientes',
      '(lo estiré para contar al &nbsp; como 1):',
      '&nbsp;<a href="http://elpais.com/diario/1978/02/22/sociedad/256950016_850215.html" style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial; display: inline; ">"Tienda&nbsp;<i>País</i>&nbsp;21.1.56abcdef890',
      '',
      'Lo mismo, pero con 29 caracteres:',
      '&nbsp;<a href="http://elpais.com/diario/1978/02/22/sociedad/256950016_850215.html" style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial; display: inline; ">"Tienda&nbsp;<i>País</i>&nbsp;21.1.56abcdef89',
      '',
      'si no contamos las etiquetas, su longitud es tan solo de 20:',
      'padre&nbsp;<b>Terreros:</b></span></div>'
     ].join('\n');



let regex = /(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])|(^|[^\S\xa0])((?:(?:<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])*(?:[^\s<[&]|\xa0|&(?:\w+;|(?!\w+;)))){30,})/g;


html = html.replace(
    regex, 
    function (m, tagExcluido, carPrevio, textoLargo) {

        //si coincidió con un tag, devolverlo sin modificar
        if (tagExcluido) return tagExcluido;
    
        //reemplazar &nbsp; y NBSP por espacios, excepto en tags
        textoLargo = textoLargo.replace(
            /(<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+])|&nbsp;|\xa0/ig,
            function (m, tagExcluido) {
                //de nuevo, ignorar tags o devolver un espacio
                return (tagExcluido ? tagExcluido : ' ');
            }
        );
        return carPrevio + textoLargo;
    }
);


//imprimir el resultado en un <pre> para verlo
document
    .getElementById('resultado')
    .innerText = html;
```

```html
<pre id="resultado" />
```

Comment: Funciona exactamente como necesitaba @Mariano. He tardado en responder porque llevo un largo tiempo intentando comprender paso a paso cada parte y no quería hacerlo sin estar seguro de que funcionase y, también, de entenderlo. Aunque me ha costado mucho entenderlo y seguiré revisitándolo en un futuro.

En cuanto a lo que me dijiste del DOM, ¿Te refieres a gestionar el texto utilizando propiedades como innerHTML? La razón por la que he elegido regex es porque son fragmentos de código html extraídos de otras webs que yo no he hecho pero que adolecen de ese problema de deformar la página.

Comment: @Pip me imagino... Tampoco me fue sencillo explicarlo en la respuesta. Si te complica alguna parte en especial, avisame y mañana veo de agregarle más descripción.

Comment: Creo que está excelentemente explicado, es sólo que para mi nivel la complejidad es extrema. Pero me ha servido y seguirá sirviendo para aprender mucho. Muchas gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 1):

Ya respondí [cómo hacerlo con regex (y sus riesgos)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/144708/127). Veamos cómo hacerlo con DOM. La idea es:

1. Generar el DOM desde el string con el HTML usando [DOMParser.parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
2. Al tener un documento, podemos recorrer cada nodo en un bucle, al igual que si fuese el document principal. En este caso uso un iterador con [createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker).
3. Dentro del bucle, diferenciar si es un tag ([ELEMENT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)) o un nodo de texto ([TEXT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)).

   1. Si es un **elemento** (tag), buscar el `style.display`. Si es `'block'` (o similar), significa que ese tag agrega un salto de línea, entonces resetear el contador de caracteres (`counter.length`) y el historial de nodos previos (`counter.nodeList`).
      Esto nos sirve para tratar elementos como `<div>` o `<p>` que naturalmente separan palabras.

      Además, se guarda en `counter.nodeBlocks` el nodo en el cual termina este elemento, para poder considerarlo como una nueva línea al final también.
   2. Si es un **nodo de texto**:

      1. Separar en palabras y/o texto entre corchetes usando

         ```
         nodo.textContent.split( /([^\S\xa0]+)|(\[[^\]]+\])/ )
         ```
      2. Recorrer cada palabra, uniendo el texto con [Array#reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).
         Dentro de la función que se evalúa en el [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce), ir sumando al contador `counter.length` el largo de cada parte de la palabra, o resetearlo si aparece un espacio.
      3. Si la última palabra aún no supera el largo (30), guardar el nodo en el array `counter.nodeList` con todos los últimos nodos que se encontraron desde el último espacio
      4. Si se supera el largo (30), reemplazar los NBSP por espacios:

         - en la palabra actual
         - en palabras previas si sólo se dividió con corchetes
         - en los últimos nodos que se guardaron (`counter.nodeList`) desde el último espacio.
      5. Si se encuentra un espacio, resetear todos los contadores (`counter.length` y `counter.nodeList`).
4. Finalmente, devolver el innerHTML.

   ```
   return doc.body.innerHTML;
   ```

---

#### Código usando DOM

```js
function replaceLongNbsp(html, minLength) {
    // GENERAR EL DOM
    let parser = new DOMParser(),
        doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html'),
        treeWalker = doc.createTreeWalker(
            doc.body,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
            null,
            false
        ),
        node;

    //defino un contador
    let counter = 
        {
            length: 0,      //largo acumulado de caracteres
            nodeList: [],   //nodos previos
            nodeBlocks: [], //fin de bloques
            //métodos
            add: function(text) {
                this.length += text.length;
            },
            addNode: function(node,lastSpace) {
                this.nodeList.push({
                    node: node,
                    lastSpace: lastSpace
                });
            },
            shiftNode: function() {
                return this.nodeList.shift();
            },
            reset: function(onlyIfNodeIsEndOfBlock) {
                //resetar el contador
                //si se pasa un nodo, sólo resetear si es el fin de display=='block'
                let end;
                if (
                    !onlyIfNodeIsEndOfBlock ||
                    this.nodeBlocks.length &&
                    !!~(end=this.nodeBlocks.indexOf(onlyIfNodeIsEndOfBlock))
                ) {
                    this.length = 0;
                    if (this.nodeList.length)
                        this.nodeList = [];
                    while (end > -1) {
                        this.nodeBlocks.splice(end,1);
                        end = this.nodeBlocks.indexOf(onlyIfNodeIsEndOfBlock);
                    }
                }
            },
            newBlock: function(node) {
                //cuando es un nuevo display=='block', resetear contador
                this.reset();
                //y guardar el nodo donde termina
                let origNode = node,
                    nodeSibling;
                while (origNode && !(nodeSibling = origNode.nextSibling)) {
                    //buscar el hermano o el hermano del padre
                    origNode = origNode.parentNode;
                }
                if (nodeSibling) {
                    this.nodeBlocks.push(nodeSibling);
                }
            }
        }
    ;
    
        
    // ITERAR CADA NODO, concatenando texto
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        node = treeWalker.currentNode;
        counter.reset(node);
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { // <TAG>
            // elemento con display=='block' ?
            if (displayBlock.check(node)) {
                //nueva línea => resetear y guardar el fin
                counter.newBlock(node);
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) { // nodo de Texto
            // separar en palabras y reemplazar si exceden el largo
            const words = node.textContent
                              .split(/([^\S\xa0]+)|(\[[^\]]+\])/)
                              .map(function(x) {return x || ''}), 
                  n = words.length - 1,
                  splits = 3;
            let lastSpace = 0;
            node.textContent = words.reduce(function(acc, word, i) {
                if (i % splits === 0) { // palabras
                    if (word.length + counter.length >= minLength) {
                        //palabra larga => REEMPLAZAR!
                        word = nbToSpFrom(word, 0, false, false);
                        //y reemplazar en toda la última palabra de este nodo
                        // (tomando las partes que separadas por corchetes)
                        nbToSpFrom(acc, lastSpace, function(x) {acc = x});
                        //y reemplazar en los nodos previos
                        let prevNode;
                        while (prevNode = counter.shiftNode()) {
                            nbToSpFrom(
                                prevNode.node.textContent,
                                prevNode.lastSpace,
                                function(x) {prevNode.node.textContent = x}
                            );
                        }
                    } else { //palabra corta
                        // acumular largo
                        counter.add(word);
                        if (i === n && counter.length) { // última => guardar nodo
                            counter.addNode(node,lastSpace);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (i % splits === 1 && word) { // espacio => borrar acumulado
                    counter.reset();
                    lastSpace = acc.length;
                }
                if (word)
                    return acc + word;
                return acc;
            }, '');
        }
    }

    return doc.body.innerHTML;
}


// función aux para modificar NBSP a espacios desde una posición
// (opcional: ignorar entre corchetes)
function nbToSpFrom(str, pos, byRefCallback, ignoreBrackets) {
    ignoreBrackets = (ignoreBrackets===undefined ? true : ignoreBrackets);
    let nbsp = (ignoreBrackets ? /(\[[^\]]*])|\xa0/g : /\xa0/g),
        modif = false;
    if (pos < str.length) {
        str = str.slice(0, pos) +
        str.slice(pos).replace(nbsp, function(m, c) {
            if (ignoreBrackets && c) return c;
            modif = true;
            return ' ';
        });
        if (modif && byRefCallback) {
           byRefCallback(str);
           return true;
        }
        return str;
    }
}

// Función aux para obtener el style.display por default de un elemento
//
var displayBlock = {};
displayBlock.checked = {};
displayBlock.check = function(node) {
    //1er intento: .style.display
    let display = node.style.display;
    if (!display) {
        let tagName = node.nodeName;
        //2do intento: si ya se buscó antes
        if (this.checked.hasOwnProperty(tagName)) {
            display = this.checked[tagName];
        } else {
            //3er intento: agregarlo a document y getComputedStyle()
            let el = document.createElement(tagName);
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            display = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).display;
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            this.checked[tagName] = display;
        }
    }
    return !~['contents', 'inline', 'table-cell', ''].indexOf(display);
}



// ------------
//    PRUEBA
// ------------

const html = [
  'laaaaaaaaaar&nbsp;goooo[foo&nbsp;bar baz]ooooooooooo&nbsp;oooooooo',
  '',
  'no haría match en este caso',
  '(en realidad coincide, pero lo devuelve sin modificar):',
  'abcdfghijklmnño<i></i>pqrstuvxyzqwerty',
  '',
  'si no contamos las etiquetas, su longitud es tan solo de 16:',
  '<div><span>padre&nbsp;<b>Terreros:&nbsp;</b></span></div>',
  '',
  'Algunos ejemplos, además del anterior, serían los siguientes',
  '(lo estiré para contar al &nbsp; como 1):',
  '&nbsp;<a href="http://elpais.com/diario/1978/02/22/256950016_850215.html"',
  'style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial;',
  'display: inline; ">"Tienda&nbsp;<i>País</i>&nbsp;21.1.56abcdef890</a>',
  '',
  'Lo mismo, pero con 29 caracteres:',
  '&nbsp;<a href="http://elpais.com/diario/1978/02/22/256950016_850215.html"',
  'style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial;',
  'display: inline; ">"Tienda&nbsp;<i>País</i>&nbsp;21.1.56abcdef89</a>',
  '',
  '<input type="text" value="esto > no_se_rompe_y_&nbsp_queda_sin_modificar">',
  '<!-- <<<>>> también_ignora_los_&nbsp;_en_comentarios <<<>>> -->',
  '',
  'Toma un <div> como nueva línea:',
  'ccccccoooooooooo&nbsp;o<div>ooooooo&nbsp;rrrrrr</div>ttttttttttt&nbsp;ooooo',
  'cooooooooooooo</div>rr&nbsp;rr[abc&nbsp;defghijklmnop]toooooooooooo',
  'llllaaaaaaaaaar&nbsprrrggggooooooooo'
].join('\n');


let resultado = replaceLongNbsp(html, 30);

// Imprimir el resultado en un <pre>
document
  .getElementById('resultado')
  .innerText = resultado;
```

```html
<pre id="resultado" />
```

Comment: Gracias por explicar este método alternativo @Mariano. Desgraciadamente (y es que mira que lo lamento), no tengo conocimientos para entender suficientemente bien lo que me has explicado aquí. Yo que pensé que sabía más o menos JavaScript y veo que sólo conozco la punta del iceberg. Gracias a tu ayuda pude acabar mi pequeño proyecto personal que usaba Html, Css y JavaScript. Mi intención ahora es aprender Java desde cero. Será un camino duro pero volveré atrás sin duda y espero que pueda entender con mayor facilidad lo que aquí me has explicado. Aunque programo solo por afición. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: No te procupes, esta respuesta la hice más por diversión que otra cosa... Sabía que te interesaba la otra... Quizás a algún otro lector :-) Me alegro que hayas podido terminar el proyecto!